# Sitecore - reusing an application-wide index searcher

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore6

Sitecore.NET 6.6.0 (rev. 130404)

In our project we are using Sitecore.Search.IndexSearchContext to perform all of our queries. Specifically, we use IndexSearchContext.Searcher method to get access to the internal Lucene searcher and pass Lucene queries to it.

I have found out (via web articles and experimentation) that if we reuse the same IndexSearchContext instance to perform all of our queries, it's significantly faster than creating and destroying an IndexSearchContext for each query that gets executed.

I have also read that IndexSearchContext is not sensitive to index updates which are made after the IndexSearchContext was created. Because of this, I'm disposing the shared IndexSearchContext and creating a new one every 30 seconds so that queries would get latest results with only a 30 second delay. This approach requires me to carefully handle thread-safety of creation and dispose of the shared index searcher.

Is this a safe approach to do things? Is it discouraged to reuse an application-wide index searcher in sitecore?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the approach and can confirm it works. I'm recreating the index searcher every 10 seconds and that has significantly improved the number of concurrent requests that can be handled. However, Sitecore's IndexSearchContext cannot be shared like this (it's intended to be created and destroyed in a single thread). What I did was instantiating a raw Lucene IndexSearcher and sharing that across the application.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you hook up to the "publish:end" and "publish:end:remote" (in a multi server environment), and drop your IndexSearchContext when these events fire. Ultimately you're in a Sitecore environment, and only when new content publishes, should your index become out of date. This version of the truth is a bit simplified, admittedly, as I don't know the full extent of the application you're running.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest I haven't seen any performance issues with spawning many IndexSearchContext. Unless you have an extreme use of it and need an extremely optimized environment, I would advise against it. I have seen a lot of problems with locked indexes and you also might run into some HTML cache issues (if used).

All in all it sounds a bit like [premature optimization](http://quotabl.es/quotes/32809). However I do not know your complete setup and I may be wrong.